# Cannot change <a> font color

Tags: css

I cannot change 5th  element in my menu. It should have blue background (it works) but I can't change the font color to white.

**CSS**

```
ul li:nth-child(5)
{
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul a:nth-child(5)
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**HTML**

```
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> <!-- This element should has other background and font -->
            <li><a href="#">01276 819291</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can u share screenshot inspecting that element

Comment: share your html please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just reuse the same pseudo selector have already as the parent of the `a` element you want to affect.

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the `a` is inside the 5th `li` child so your CSS shoud be like this:

```
ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are matching for `a` matches for a hyperlink which is the 5th child of something. If you want to color all hyperlinks within the 5th item of an unsorted list, you want to match for `ul li:nth-child(5) a`:

```
ul li:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #FFF;
}
```